# In search of a lost question

Tags: support, questions, answers, deleted-questions

A while ago (don't remember when) I gave an answer to a question about constructing Archimedean spiral using `NDSolve` for a differential equation on curvature as the function of the arclength.

It so happened that I actually need to use the method I then described for some other task of mine. But I cannot find that anywhere anymore. Maybe the OP has deleted it, but I also don't remember who the OP was.

Is there any way to recover that answer somehow?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to look through all of the questions you've answered here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35000/%e1%83%9b%e1%83%90%e1%83%9b%e1%83%a3%e1%83%99%e1%83%90-%e1%83%af%e1%83%98%e1%83%91%e1%83%9a%e1%83%90%e1%83%ab%e1%83%94?tab=answers

Comment: Could it be [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214834/142)?  The OP self-answered after your extensive comments provided key insights.

Comment: @WReach OH thank you so much! Now I understand, I did not remember that I actually did not answer it! How did you find it?

Comment: Google search succeeded where MSE search failed... MSE could not find the question even when presented with words in the title.  Strange.

Comment: @WReach Good to know! I think I will still leave the question open, since there might be also cases that I hypothesized (when one needs to find a closed question).